# Orbbec Astra on ROS issues

Tags: ros, 3dcamera, camera, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently purchased a Deep Learning Robot. https://www.autonomous.ai/deep-learning-robot   Mine came with the Orbbec Astra instead of the Asus Live Pro.  I'm trying to get it up and running but having issues. In RViz, I can see RGB fine, but, the depth sensors don't work when I toggle them on.  I'm brand new to ROS and following the Turtlebot tutorials.   I found this thread on the subject. https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-depth-sensor-orbbec-astra-call-for-testing/252/22  but, I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

More Info:

I'm getting this..

```
In PointCloud: Transform [sender=unknown_publisher] For frame [camera_rgb_optical_frame]: Fixed Frame [base_footprint] does not exist

In Registerd PointCloud: Transform [sender=unknown_publisher] For frame [camera_rgb_optical_frame]: Fixed Frame [base_footprint] does not exist
```

also getting these as well

```
In Grid: For frame [odom]: Fixed Frame [base_footprint] does not exist

RobotModel: Parameter [robot_description] does not exist, and was not found by searchParam()
```

I ran this on the robot: `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch`

and this on the PC: `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch`

Thanks, Billy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252139/orbbec-astra-on-ros-issues/) by [Connor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29074/connor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Probably not the answer you're looking for, but seeing as you actually bought this configuration from a company: have you tried contacting them and asking this question? We're happy to help, but this would seem like a prime example of the sort of question you'd ask the company's support department.

**Comment by [Connor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29074/connor/) on 2017-01-17**:
I bought it never assembled from a 3rd party.  Not direct from the company.  Strange thing is, their site still showing the Asus Axiton Pro Live vs the Orbbec Astra.

**Comment by [rohbotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/23169/rohbotics/) on 2017-01-22**:
In your rviz screen shot (on discourse) it shows status error,
If you expand the status (arrow on the left of the status), what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a lot for us to go on here.

My typical debugging process would be to ask and answer the following questions:

- Is there an error displayed in rivz? If you expand the display properties it will show you some status that usually includes number of messages or points received, and sometimes errors.
- Which topic is rviz subscribing to for "depth sensors" ? This should be listed in rviz display that you're enabling when you try to view the point cloud.
- Which topics are the Orbbec Astra driver publishing? You can start to identify this by figuring out which node(s) are the Orbbec Astra driver, and then run rqt_graph or rosnode info to see which topics it's publishing
- Sanity check: Is rviz subscribing to a reasonable topic? Compare the topic that rivz is subscribing to with the list of topics that the driver is publishing.
- Is there data published on the topic that rviz is subscribing to? Use `rostopic echo` or `rostopic hz` to see if there is data published on that topic that rviz is subscribing to
- If there is data published, why can't rviz display it? This usually goes back to the top, looking at rviz to see why it's not displaying the data.

Please try to go through these steps and answers these questions on your own. If you get stuck, feel free to **edit your question** with additional information, and please include the details, either copy and paste commands and their output, or include a screenshot of rviz.

**EDIT**

Given that the transforms for `base_footprint` is missing and the `robot_description` parameter is missing, it seems like the main turtlebot launch file isn't running on your robot. I believe this is the `minimal.launch` in the turtlebot package, but you should consult the manual to be certain.

I also find it odd that you're running rviz on the robot, and the Orbbec driver on your desktop. It seems to be working, but it implies that you're visualizing things on the robot (are you chasing it around with a monitor attached?), while the Orbbec sensor is plugged in to your desktop and, presumably, stationary.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Connor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29074/connor/) on 2017-01-22**:
I cut'n pasted the commands backwards.. I am indeed running rivz on the laptop and the orbbec on the robot.   It seems that I missed the VERY **critical** step of:  Make sure the minimal software has already been launched on the robot and you have configured your network correctly.